# Add property to a list

Tags: list, properties, addition

I have alist of images and unfortunately, there's no way to tell the path to those images, so, I'm thinking of including the path as an attribute of the list. Is that possible?

```
private List<DicomImage> img = new List<DicomImage>();
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you are using, you can use a map/dictionary data structure and use the paths as the keys and images as values.

Comment: Thanks, I found another way, using the functions of the Dicom images anyways, thanks for the answer!